# Problem changing button size when pressed in Android

Tags: android, button

I have tried changing the size of my button when I press it but nothing seem to work.

The button is created in main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<Button
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
android:layout_height="90px" 
android:id="@+id/button1" 
android:layout_marginTop="120px"
android:layout_width="90px"         
android:textSize="45px" 
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@drawable/bnumber" 
android:text="1">
</Button>
```

And the code for the button logic is:

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                sendMessage("key1\n");
                button1.setWidth(140);
                button1.setHeight(140);
            }
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                button1.setWidth(90);
                button1.setHeight(90);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

From googling I am quite sure this should work, but for some reason it doesn't.

My device uses Android 1.6, could this be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set button width and height using the following code to set button width and height

```
button1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (LayoutParams) b.getLayoutParams();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            sendMessage("key1\n");
            lp.width=140;
            lp.height=140;
            button1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            lp.width=90;
            lp.height=90;
            button1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

When you got the event ACTION_DOWN, if you return false, you couldn't get ACTION_UP event.
Try change

```
return false;
```

to

```
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

`onTouchListener` is used to [handle motion events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29). Try using `onClickListener` instead.

**ACTION_UP** and **ACTION_DOWN** are used to indicate gestures (see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html)), not pressing / releasing the button.

Comment: The problem with 'onClickListener' was that the message was send after releasing the button, not when pressing.