# How to use style in selector?

Tags: android

I want to increase textSize of button when selector state_pressed and bring it normal size for other state.

Please help to know how to use style for state_pressed? I did not find any option in selector.

For now I am just changing background color with selector, let me know if we can use style in selector that way can change textSize through style.

```
    // fragment's xml
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_level3"
        android:text="@string/level3"
        android:textColor="#99CC00"
        style="@style/ButtonNormal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"/>           

-----------------------------------------------------------

    // styles.xml
    <style name="ButtonPressed">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/button_pressed</item>
    </style>

-----------------------------------------------------------

    // buttom_custom.xml
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/color_highlight" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
    </selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set button width and height using the setOnTouchListener method on your Button. Refer this [Problem changing button size when pressed in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183934/problem-changing-button-size-when-pressed-in-android).

Answer (score 0):

> ya mahdi aj
>   -- create btn.xml in drawable then paste:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="false">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/formbtn"/>
                <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/transparent" />

            </shape>
        </item>
        <item android:state_pressed="true">
            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <solid android:color="@color/formbtnborder"/>
                <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="@color/transparent" />
            </shape>
        </item>
    </selector>
```