# Android button animate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-button

I have these buttons here and i want them both to have some animation onclick.
To grow up a little bit and then return to normal.

Here are the buttons xml codes.

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="next"
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:src="@drawable/next"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/linearLayout" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="confirm"
        android:src="@drawable/confirm"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />
```

These buttons are on one activity_main.xml file.

Can someone help me showing me some stuff of what should i do to make it happen?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: https://github.com/duslee/CustomButton

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Very nice example but what i mean is that the button should grow up a little bit when i click it and when i leave the button it should go back the same.

Comment: Please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183934/problem-changing-button-size-when-pressed-in-android .Just check the logic

Comment: I hope above url fulfill your requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Animator` can achieve the goal easily:

```
findViewById(R.id.next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Animator scale = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(v,
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_X, 1, 1.5f, 1),
                    PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat(View.SCALE_Y, 1, 1.5f, 1)
                    );
            scale.setDuration(1000);
            scale.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: i get error ("cannot resolve symbol "objectanimator" and "propertyvaluesholder") any idea of what should i declare for these 2?

Comment: What is your target api? If you want to use `Animator`, the target api should be above 11.

Comment: minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23

Comment: Have you added such import `import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder;`?

Comment: yup but when i try to run it, it crashes with this error.     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ioulios.ellak/com.example.ioulios.ellak.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: i have imagebutton not button.

Answer (score 1):

In the button's onclick, we start the animation we want to use using the `view.startAnimation()` method. We first load the required animation using `AnimationUtils.loadAnimation()`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        view.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.button_click));            
    }
}
```

Now create a file under the anim folder called button_click.xml or whatever you want to name it.

> anim/button_click.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
    android:fromXScale = "1"
    android:toXScale = "0.9"
    android:fromYScale = "1"
    android:toYScale = "0.9"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration = "50">
    </scale>
</set>
```

Comment: under the drawable folder?

Comment: i get errors ("cannot resolve symbol the name of my button "confirm")

Comment: hmmm. where are you putting your button_click file?

Comment: res>anim>button_click ... i declare some stuff and i have no errors now only in the last  "}" it says  ( ',' or ')' is expected)

Comment: seems like you are getting a syntax error. Can you show me your code?

Comment: the hole main_activity?

Comment: No, just the ones related to the button reference.